# Zoom using javascript in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a problem regarding implementing a magnifier in visualforce page.

When we point the mouse cursor on a field or image on a visualforce page it should appear zoomed.

How do i implement this using javascript?
Please help.

the following code doesnt work:

```
<apex:page > 
    <apex:image url="upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/…; 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Event.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Magnifier.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var evt = new Event(), m = new Magnifier(evt); 
    </script> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You should be able to incorporate JavaScript such as [Magnifier.js](http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/) to zoom images. I am not aware of anything that zooms form fields though.

Comment: i mean the image should magnify when we hover the mouse on it. So if any suggestions for writing the code

Comment: My suggestion is that you add a JavaScript library such as the one I provided a link to in my comment to your page.

Comment: which library could u please post it here

Comment: Google yourself and choose. My first comment includes a link to one I found by Googling but there may be others that are better.

Comment: <apex:page >
<apex:image url="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg/1600px-Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Magnifier.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var evt = new Event(),
    m = new Magnifier(evt);
</script>
</apex:page>

Comment: the above code doesnt work

Comment: Your references to the script files won't work. If the JavaScript is not available via a CDN location you will have to add it to your project as a static resource and reference it from there. Please research that yourself and also the basics of how to debug JavaScript.